# Why my app is not available to some devices via Market?

Tags: android

My app is not available to below listed Devices

Samsung GT D-5330
Samsung GT 7262

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Comment: post your androidManifest.xml file. We can't help you without it.

Comment: What are the permissions you are using in your Manifest file ?

Comment: You can optimize your Manifestfile for support more number of Devices by some specefic methods : for help check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017627/optimizing-android-manifest-file-for-largest-number-of-supported-devices

Answer (score 0):

Did u added

```
<!-- Donut-specific flags which allow us to run on any dpi screens. -->
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

in your Manifest??

Answer (score 0):

If you add all lines in the first answer, maybe you need to add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

Some old devices need that to works.