# Google play Supported device 0

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I published an application but google play shows me that 0 devices are compatible.
I checked the Manifest but i don't know why.

I tried to change minsdk and targetsdk but the result is the same.

I need help please!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.h2_web.www.agos"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icona"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".services.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="YouWillNeverKillMe" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.MyService"></service>

        <activity
            android:name=".Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ImmobiliView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ClientiView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ImmobiliList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ClientiList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WebActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AgendaView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactsView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link for solution

[Optimizing Android manifest file for largest number of supported devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017627/optimizing-android-manifest-file-for-largest-number-of-supported-devices)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html