# Limit android app only for Mobile phones not tablet

Tags: android, screen, tablet

I want my application available only for mobile phones not for tablet. Here is what i have done

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="soulvant.golfclub">

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>


<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<!-- for Samsung badge -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />

<!-- for htc badge -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />

<!-- for sony badge -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />

<!-- for apex badge -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<permission
    android:name="soulvant.golfclub.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="soulvant.golfclub.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".utils.ApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="replace">
    <meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="aurous.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="soulvant.golfclub" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProsDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProDetailRateOffer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.NewsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.NewsDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.EventsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.EventDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CourseActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CourseDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FacilityAvailableActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CourseRateoffActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RestaurantActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RestaurantMenu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RestaurantDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RestaurantRatesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HotelsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HotelDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HotelPackageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HotelWebsiteActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProshopActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProshopDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CoursesSlideshow"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProshopRateOfferActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.BrowserActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AdvertisementActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Advertisement"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="soulvant.golfclub" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

But when i uploaded it on playstore and tried to search on my samsung galaxy s4 it was not there is search result.

What i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can u post entire manifest.. Are u using anything like <uses-feature?

Comment: Here is my full manifiest @Raghavendra

Comment: I think @IntelliJ Amiya's answer will work

Comment: @Android . You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017627/optimizing-android-manifest-file-for-largest-number-of-supported-devices

Answer (score 4):

> Android makes it easy to develop an app that runs well on a wide range
>   of device screen sizes and form factors. This broad compatibility
>   works in your favor, since it helps you design a single app that you
>   can distribute widely to all of your targeted devices. However, to
>   give your users the best possible experience on each screen
>   configuration — in particular on tablets — you need to optimize your
>   layouts and other UI components for each targeted screen
>   configuration. On tablets, optimizing your UI lets you take full
>   advantage of the additional screen available, such as to offer new
>   features, present new content, or enhance the experience in other ways
>   to deepen user engagement.

Add this

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

> An application "supports" a given screen size if it resizes properly
>   to fill the entire screen. Normal resizing applied by the system works
>   well for most applications and you don't have to do any extra work to
>   make your application work on screens larger than a handset device.
>   However, it's often important that you optimize your application's UI
>   for different screen sizes by providing alternative layout resources.
>   For instance, you might want to modify the layout of an activity when
>   it is on a tablet compared to when running on a handset device.

Please read official Document's about **[Declare Support for Tablet Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#support-screens)** & **[supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)** . I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score -1):

If you do not specify a large screen size in manifest, it will not show up in tablet, so don't worry about that.

[image]

So, now it wont show up for tablets in the play store unless you do something to show up in play store.

**You stated your app doesn't show up on the `Samsung galaxy s4`:**

Your app has permissions that the samsung galaxy s4 cannot handle. For example, if you try to access a camera on a device without a camera, then your app wont show up for that device. So, take a look at the permissions in the app you made, and look at the features of the s4, check which ones it cannot abide to.

Comment: @Android I know why, and if this helps, please press the check mark to accept this answer. Your app has permissions that the samsung galaxy s4 cannot handle. For example, if you try to access a camera on a device without a camera, then your app wont show up for that device. So, take a look at the permissions in the app you made, and look at the features of the s4, check which ones it cannot abide to.

Comment: i uploaded this app without <compatible screens> tag previously and it was showing at that time. Clients asked me to make it available only for handsets not for tablets i added <Compatible screens > after this app wont show on my s4

Comment: @Android Add this to manifest `<screen
    android:screenDensity="480"
    android:screenSize="normal" /> `