# Will this work on all screen sizes?

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-activity, optimization

I've been doing lots of research lately on optimizing my app for all screen sizes. I've created 9 of every layout in order to fit every size.

Don't worry about those other two layouts that are just in the `layout` directory, I will make 8 more of those later

(Android view)
[image]

Some articles say to have more layouts, but of what? Am I missing something? **Did I do this correctly?**

I have some doubt about my screen sizes, as lots of people on the internet have different ways of targeting different devices, is this correct?

```
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Do I need to add more compatible screens? Because other documents have a lot more. Will my app show up on all devices, like tablets?

**Is there anything I missed in order to be optimized for all devices, like tablets and phones? Must I create any new layouts or add more compatible screen permissions in the manifest?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

> An application "supports" a given screen size if it resizes properly
>   to fill the entire screen. Normal resizing applied by the system works
>   well for most applications and you don't have to do any extra work to
>   make your application work on screens larger than a handset device.
>   However, it's often important that you optimize your application's UI
>   for different screen sizes by providing alternative layout resources.
>   For instance, you might want to modify the layout of an activity when
>   it is on a tablet compared to when running on a handset device.

Please read official Document's about **[Declare Support for Tablet Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#support-screens)** & **[supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)** . I hope it will helps you .

```
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<!-- all xlarge size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```

Courtesy Goes to **[Optimizing Android manifest file for largest number of supported devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017627/optimizing-android-manifest-file-for-largest-number-of-supported-devices)**

Comment: Okay, am I missing anything in my layout folders? Am I supposed to only have 9? Will my app show up for tablets?

Comment: Yes, I read both the links. Still don't know if I have enough layout folders

Comment: `compatible-screens` Looks like perfect .

Comment: No, thats now what I'm asking. My question is whether 9 layout folders is enough for all screen sizes. Look at my screen shot, will it work for all screen sizs?

Comment: @NullPointerException Okay now i understand . You can add some extra permission .Please check my edited answer .

Comment: No, that is still not what Im asking. See my screen shot? It has 9 layouts, right? IS THAT ENOUGH? Do I need more layouts? Thanks

Comment: @NullPointerException No .You have enough Layouts

Comment: Are you sure? A lot of places I see people with 10-20 layouts...So I'm good?

Comment: @NullPointerException . You can visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428096/design-layout-for-multiple-screens

Comment: Okay, so I have been researching for an hour now, and I am confused. Do I include both the compatible screens and the supported screens? Or just one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850115/difference-between-supports-screens-and-compatible-screens-on-android I would prefer `compatible-screens`

Comment: Okay thanks, so I'm actually only going to include the `supportsScreens`. So, you're absolutely sure that my app will show up on every android device made? (not counting ones under the min sdk)

Comment: I think that is incorrect because I tried this solution : before 7388 divices with your lines 6428 ....

Comment: @delive Okay , i will change my answer . What is `before 7388 divices with your lines 6428` ??

Comment: I used to have 7388 devices available with your lines I have eliminated approximately 950 , 7388 - 960 = 6428 devices available,  I lose devices